# Design issue with WCF

Tags: wcf, design-patterns

I have a Service which references a DLL containing the Service Contract, and the implementation is in a service hosted in IIS.

I am using a client which also references that same DLL.

I am calling the service methods using channel factory and my server endpoints are defined manually in client section of my client `app.config`

All of my service methods need to know the connection string before initiating any database operation. Now I don't want to create connection on each function request as it will degrade the performance and my service is common for most of my other components and I want to make it in a generic way

Is there any utility or design pattern I can use in WCF ?

Comment: Actually, I would **recommend** to always open the database connection **as late as possible** before making the db call, and **closing** the connection again as quickly as possible. Don't open your connection when the service starts up and keep it open for an extended period of time!

Comment: marc you are always helpful ,thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but based on what you wrote above it seems you may be overthinking the situation.

If your service methods need to know the connection string (prior to making any database operations), why not just put it in the Web.config file for the service?

That would seem to make the most sense, to me.  Unless there are some other factors/considerations that I missed or am not aware of?

Also, depending on how your doing your database access, .NET does implement connection pooling (at least in ADO.NET).  See here:

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)